# phpmyadmin 4.9.4: i cannot use edit, drop, & delete. 'no database selected'

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, apache, phpmyadmin

I'm running into a very unusual problem.  phpmyadmin will not let me use the edit, drop, or delete buttons/links without throwing a 'no database selected' error.  although when i check the box for the table i would like to drop it shows a 'error in processing request: undefined' error.

i can create databases, import databases, i can even double click on row values, change the row value, & submit it with success.  literally i can use every other feature.  but if i use the drop, delete, or edit row button/link i get the `no database selected` error.

i even checked my user priv's and set them to max privs for everything but i'm not having priv problems.  the only thing i can think of is somehow a value isn't getting passed to let the script know i have the database selected when i try to submit a change w/ a button/link.

checked the console on my chrome browser and i'm getting hit with 10+ different jQuery errors.  ex: `JQMIGRATE: jQuery.fn.*() is deprecated; use jQuery.*
also 
[DOM] Found 2 elements with non-unique id #showAll_478134533:`

I'm running phpmyadmin on localhost it's for my personal webserver so I can test my php code without uploading to my server constantly.  my cfg is `Apache/2.4.41 (Win64) PHP/7.4.2.`  I'm beginning to think it's something in my php.ini or i didn't add something to my httpd.conf for apache.  any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem on https://demo.phpmyadmin.net/QA_4_9/ ?

Comment: i couldn't figure it out.  so i dropped my php.ini and replaced it w/ a default one and now it works fine.  so it was something in the php.ini that was breaking phpmyadmin.  i still couldn't find the exact setting that was preventing it from working properly.  i know i had problems w/ PMA before because of a global array setting, specifically the (request_order).

Comment: php allows you to set the order w/ variables_order "EGPCS"  and you can leave the request_order "" blank.  it says the request_order will borrow the order from variables_order if left blank.  i did that but for some reason with it set like that the "loading..." popup would not go away and it would make all the links unusable.

to fix it i changed the variables_order from no setting back to variables_order "GP".  that fixed the issue.

Comment: I am having the same issues, any fix? I have variables_order = "GPCS"